# Is $[ G^i, G^i]$ always normal in $G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G^1 = [G, G]$ and $G^i = [G^{i-1}, G^{i-1}]$, then is it true that $G^i$ is normal in $G$?

My approach: 
Since it is true for $i = 1$. Assume by induction it is true for $i \leq n-1$. If $\alpha \in [G^i, G^i] = g^{i+1}$, then $\alpha = aba^{-1}b^{-1} $ where $a, b \in G^i$. Therefore $$g\alpha g^{-1} = gaba^{-1}b^{-1}g^{-1} = gaba^{-1}(g^{-1}b^{-1}bg)b^{-1}g^{-1} = \big((ga)b(a^{-1}g^{-1})b^{-1}\big) \cdot\big(bgb^{-1}g^{-1}\big) \in G^{i+1}.$$ Hence $G^{i+1}$ is normal.

Somehow I am finding this result powerful and yet I am unable to find any reference which talks abouts this, so I am guessing I am making some mistake. Can someone confirm this.

Comment: Yes it's normal, it's called the derived series and any introductory algebra book should talk about it.

Comment: The usual way to prove this is to show that $[G,G]$ is characteristic in $G$, and since being characteristic is a transitive property, it follows that $G^i$ is characteristic and hence normal.

Comment: Actually it's even better : $G^i$ is characteristic in $G$ and this follows by induction from the fact that $[G,G]$ is characteristic in $G$ and that characteristicity is transitive

Comment: The other way is to show that $[H,K]$ is normal in $G$ if both $H$ and $K$ are.  To see this, note that the conjugate of a commutator of two elements is equal to the commutator of the conjugates.

Comment: Also please note that you mean $G^{(i)}$ for the derived series, not $G^i$, which is from the lower central series.   $G^{(i+1)}=[G^{(i)},G^{(i)}]$, whilst $G^{i+1}=[G^i,G]$.